# Number items from list according to Set item

Tags: list, java-8, set, java-stream

I'm using a class to performs my questions...

```
public class Competitor {
  private final int type;
  private final String name;
  private final int power;

  public Competitor(int type, String name, int power) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.power = power;
  }

  public int getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getPower() {
    return power;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Competitor{" + "type=" + type + ", name=" + name + ", power=" + power + "} ";
  }
}
```

Now I created a nestedList of my before class

```
List<List<Competitor>> nestedCompetitor = new ArrayList<>(); 

List<Competitor> listCompetitors0 = new ArrayList<>();

listCompetitors0.add(new Competitor(1, "Cat 00", 93));
listCompetitors0.add(new Competitor(1, "Cat 10", 11));
listCompetitors0.add(new Competitor(1, "Cat 23", 20));

List<Competitor> listCompetitors1 = new ArrayList<>();
listCompetitors1.add(new Competitor(2, "Dog 61", 54));
listCompetitors1.add(new Competitor(2, "Dog 18", 40));
listCompetitors1.add(new Competitor(2, "Dog 45", 71));
listCompetitors1.add(new Competitor(2, "Dog 30", 68));

List<Competitor> listCompetitors2 = new ArrayList<>();
listCompetitors2.add(new Competitor(3, "Pig 90", 90));
listCompetitors2.add(new Competitor(3, "Pig 78", 20));

List<Competitor> listCompetitors3 = new ArrayList<>();
listCompetitors3.add(new Competitor(4, "Cow 99", 90));

nestedCompetitor.add(listCompetitors0);
nestedCompetitor.add(listCompetitors1);
nestedCompetitor.add(listCompetitors2);
nestedCompetitor.add(listCompetitors3);
```

I got ordered `Set` classified by `Power`

```
Set<Integer> setLastPower = nestedCompetitor.stream()
        .map(l -> l.get(l.size() - 1).getPower())
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));

List<Integer> account = new ArrayList<>();
Long iterations = 1L;
for (Integer powerSet: setLastPower) {
    Integer powerCount =
    (int)nestedCompetitor.stream()
        .map(l -> l.get(l.size() - 1).getPower())
            .filter(powerList -> powerList.equals(powerSet)).count();
    account.add(powerCount);
    System.out.println("powerSet:" + powerSet + " -> " + "number items:" + powerCount);
    iterations *=(long)powerCount;
}
System.out.println("iterations:" + iterations);
```

`powerCount` is *number items*.

Now, **I want to obtain the number items from `List` according to each `Set` item**.

I know I can to use a create a filter taken from item Set, applied to List and make count.

**But, is there optimized options?**

Comment: Can you write an example of what the output should look like? It's unclear from your description.

Comment: What “number items”? Do you mean the size of the lists?

Comment: are you trying to say that you want to order the list based on the order of the obtained Set? Wouldn't that be straightforward with comparator such that it compares the power of the last element of each list? On the other hand, if you wanted to count, obtaining them to Set to start with was a bit off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Map<Integer,Long> map = nestedCompetitor.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        l -> l.get(l.size() - 1).getPower(), list -> 1L, Long::sum,
        () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.<Integer>reverseOrder())));

map.forEach((powerSet,powerCount) ->
    System.out.println("powerSet:" + powerSet + " -> " + "powerCount:" + powerCount));

Long iterations = map.values().stream().reduce(1L, Math::multiplyExact);

System.out.println("iterations:" + iterations);
```

Alternatively

```
Map<Integer,Long> map = nestedCompetitor.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(l.size() - 1).getPower(),
        () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.<Integer>reverseOrder()),
        Collectors.counting()));

map.forEach((powerSet,powerCount) ->
    System.out.println("powerSet:" + powerSet + " -> " + "powerCount:" + powerCount));

Long iterations = map.values().stream().reduce(1L, Math::multiplyExact);

System.out.println("iterations:" + iterations);
```

Common to both is to count the occurrences right in the collect operation. Usually, you’ll find one of the two collectors, `toMap` or `groupingBy`, more suitable to a particular task, but here, it makes not much difference.

In principle, `toMap` will be more efficient when there are a lot of distinct keys and rather small numbers of occurrences for each, whereas `groupingBy` will be one step ahead when there’s rather a small number of distinct keys with rather large numbers of elements for each (though, in case of `counting()`, this only applies to Java 9 or newer).

Comment: I greatly appreciate your opinion and suggestions for improvement in the code I have submitted for my response https://stackoverflow.com/a/56343793/1410223